# How to shift all values from an array but remove the last value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And I want to shift all the values and remove the last value and put 0.
My array should look like this after the operation :

```js
[2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
```

How to do this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any attempts?

Comment: A loop from `1` to `array.length - 1` + a `.push()`, `.shift()` + `.push()`, ...

Comment: @Kosh I don't really know why but I just can't seem to find a way to start, my brain refuses ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one approach

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            arr.shift()
            arr.push(0)
            
 console.log(arr)
```

second approach

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];           
v=arr.slice(1,arr.lenth)
console.log([...v,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this useful in java. Note - this approach will manipulate the original array

```
    private void circularArray(int originalArray[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length -1; i++) {
        originalArray[i] = originalArray[i+1];
    }
    originalArray[originalArray.length -1] = 0;
}
```